# Can we generalize matrix model theory?

Tags: tensor-calculus, matrix-model

As in the question, can matrix model theory be generalized to a tensor model theory? Will the results be different or useful in describing real world phenomena?

Details: in matrix model theory we have an $N\times N$ matrix $M$ with the action given by $S=\dfrac 1g \int \text{tr} (M^2 +V(M) )  DM$, so can we replace $M= (M_{ij}) $ by $T_{ijk} $ for example, so that the free Lagrangian becomes $T_{ijk} T_{jik}$ or something alike?

Comment: There are several things that are called "matrix model". Please elaborate what exactly you mean here and how a generalization to "tensor model" is supposed to work (beyond merely replacing the word "matrix" with "tensor").

Comment: I have edited the question.